# Compare Date list with Date

Tags: java, arrays, spring, date, sap-commerce-cloud

I get from a query a list of days existing in DB and I have to take from this list of dates every single date and compare it with a date (if they match I go to set some data otherwise this pattern is set in the column "- / - ").
The problem is that I can't (once the comparison is made) move to the next date on the list. Here is the piece of code:

error on log "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2" is on this row : if (el.getDays().get(i).toString().equals(day.toString()))

```
int i = 0;
private void createAndFillDayCells(final List<OrderDeliveringModel> orderDeliveringModelList, final DateFormat df,
        final OrderDeliveringModel el, final Row storeRow, final Date day)
{
    int index = el.getDays().indexOf(day);
    Column dayCol = new Column();
    dayCol.setStyle(COLUMN_HEADERS_STYLE);
    
    Label day1;
    day.setHours(00);
    day.setMinutes(00);
    day.setSeconds(00);
    int dayOfWeek = TimeSlotDateUtils.getDayOfWeek(day);
    String dayString = getDayOfWeekAsString(dayOfWeek);

    Label headerLabel = new Label(dayString + " " + df.format(day));
    dayCol.appendChild(headerLabel);

    columns.appendChild(dayCol);
    if (el.getDays().get(i).toString().equals(day.toString()))

    {
        day1 = new Label(el.getOrderCount().get(i) + " / " + el.getTotalCapacity().get(i));
        day1.setAttribute("storePlusDate", el.getStore().getStoreRef() + "*" + 
        df.format(day));
        i++;
    }

    else
    {
        day1 = new Label(" - / - ");
        day1.setAttribute("storePlusDate", el.getStore().getStoreRef() + "*" + 
        df.format(day));

    }
    
    storeRow.appendChild(day1);
}
```

Comment: Are you calling your method once too many, i.e., whne `i` equals the number of days? A [mre], please?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. If you don’t want and need time of day, use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Even if you insist on using `Date`, definitely stay far away from its `setXxx` methods. They have been deprecated for more than 25 years because they work unreliably across time zones.

Comment: I do fix on this code that are write from another developer.. and I got become crazy :D

Comment: I understand, @Mike. Your craze will likely diminish as soon as you get `Date` out of the code and replace it by the sane `LocalDate` class.

Comment: @OleV.V. How can I best implement LocalDate?

Comment: That's a big question for a comment. Declare `LocalDate` instead of `Date` in your method. Compare dates through `equals()` or `isEqual()`. Where you must interface with legacy code, convert. Look up how.

Answer (score 1):

According to me, if you have already fetched the date and it is with you then you can simply convert full date to string then split the string by "/" then it will be an array of string fetch the date from it. In this process you can also compare it with the date and can do your required job.

If you have `List<Date> dates` like this, the code can be

```
for(Date date:dates) {
    String s_date=date+"";
    String[] date_array=s_date.split("/");
}
```

Now you have a date as a string in each loop then you can compare it.